# How can I cache something inside a variable in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I get some JSON from an online API and I want to cache the response for until my application is running.

How can I cache the output of that API in Next.js?

I don't want to use a third party library just to store a simple JSON object somewhere.

In C# I simply create a static variable and it's there for the lifetime of my process.

How can I do it in Next.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the data in an exported variable. All modules that import it will share a single, read-only live binding to that variable (so they see updates to it, but can't change it).

If you don't want it holding up loading and you don't mind coding around it not being there, then:

```
export let theData = null;
getTheData()
.then(data => {
    theData = data;
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...error handling...
});
```

Anything using `import { theData } from "the-module";` will have a live binding to that.

If you don't want to code around it possibly being `null`, you could export a promise and then use (say) `await` with it; say you were using `fetch` to fetch the data:

```
export const theData = fetch(/*...the data...*/)
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok){
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    return response.json();
});
```

Then anything using it would await the import.